# How to get RavenDb Id from Type and value?

Tags: ravendb

In the [RavenDb documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/working-with-document-ids) I can get the document Id if I pass in my object:

```
string orderId = session.Advanced.GetDocumentId(order); // "orders/1"
```

but what I would like is to just pass in the type and the object's id value instead, like:

```
string orderId = session.Advanced.GetDocumentId(typeof(Order), 1); // "orders/1"
```

Is this at all possible? If so, how? I'm trying to avoid having to pull the object out of the database before I delete it. I'm having RavenDb generate the collection names so I don't want to make any assumptions about the name.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this from the document store's conventions, using the `FindFullDocumentKeyFromNonStringIdentifier` method.

Here's a simple extension method that will help:

```
public static string GetStringIdFor<T>(this IDocumentStore documentStore, int id)
{
    return documentStore.Conventions.FindFullDocumentKeyFromNonStringIdentifier(id, typeof(T), false);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
string orderId = documentStore.GetStringIdFor<Order>(1);
```

Or, if you don't happen to have access to the document store at that point in your code, you can grab it from the session:

```
string orderId = session.Advanced.DocumentStore.GetStringIdFor<Order>(1);
```